# Como manter o Menu Accordion aberto após clicar no link e paginar?

Tags: javascript

Preciso que o panel do link clicado permaneça aberto na nova página

**Por exemplo:**

Ao clicar no Link 3

direciona para pg3 com a Section 1 aberta

[adaptação de w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol)

Obs: o link clicado é marcado na nova página usando:

if($cod == $codin) {coloca o link em bold-red}

Talvez se incluir if no js, pode resolver (não sei como fazer)

**AJUDA**

Tenho vários menus com mais de 200 links e este recurso de menu acordeon é fundamental para facilitar a navegação

**Vcs podem me indicar um menu acordeon**

- que mantenha a Section aberta (se possível, marcar o link escolhido)
- e abre uma Section e fecha outra

Agradeço imensamente a ajuda

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
this.classList.toggle("active");

var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
if (panel.style.maxHeight){
   panel.style.maxHeight = null;
}
else {
  panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
}});}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <li><a href="pg1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="pg2">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="pg3">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="pg4">Link 4</a></li>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <li><a href="pg5">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="pg6">Link 7</a></li>
</div>
```